# how to use twemproxy for redis partitioning?

Tags: redis

I have read http://antirez.com/news/44 and https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy. I have configured nutcracker. But I don't know how to open redis-cli using it. Anybody has answer?
I want to know that how to start nutcracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as you would do with redis. Specify port from nutcracker configuration

redis-cli -p 22122

```
alpha:
  listen: 127.0.0.1:22121
  hash: fnv1a_64
  distribution: ketama
  auto_eject_hosts: true
  redis: true
  server_retry_timeout: 2000
  server_failure_limit: 1
  servers:
   - 127.0.0.1:6379:1
```